# Combine wmts and wms

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, wms

I want to combine a WMS with a WMTS. I work with OL 
3.10.1. alone or combine only WMS there is no problem with the services in the application. The WMTS service alone works correctly in my OL3-Application.

But when I add a WMS to the WMTS OL3 generate WMS-GetMap-Requests with `&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&`, although all my services based on EPSG 25832 (the WMTS also). The WMS-Response contains then the ServiceException code InvalidSRS. When I copy the wms-getmap-request and replace 3857 to 25832 the response is a correct map.

In my OL3-Application I test also with a projection-object with no success.

```js
var layer_wmts=new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.WMTS({
   url: 'https://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/xxxx',
   layer:'xxx',
   matrixSet:'DE_EPSG_25832_ADV',
   tileGrid: tileGrid,
   format: 'image/png',
   style: 'normal',
   projection: 'EPSG:25832'
   })
  });
  
var layer_grenzen=new ol.layer.Image({
 source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
 url:'http://intra-entumn1.vkv.niedersachsen.de/fcgi-bin/ows/verwaltungsgrenzen',
 params: {'LAYERS': 'AG',VERSION: '1.1.1',defaultProjection:'EPSG:25832',projection:'EPSG:25832'}
    })
 }); 
 
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [layer_wmts,layer_grenzen],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({center:[594560.,5806642.],zoom:8,minZoom:7,maxZoom:18}),
  controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([new ol.control.ScaleLine(),new ol.control.MousePosition({coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(0)})
  ]),
});
```

What can I do to combine WMTS and WMS in OL3?

Answer (score 0):

runs with projection-object, when combine wmts and wms (default projection is 3857).

```
var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'EPSG:25832',
  extent: [ -1878007.03, 3932282.86, 831544.53, 9437501.55]
});

// …

var view = new ol.View({
  projection: projection
  // …
});
```